# How to define sum result's width?

Tags: vhdl

I have few unsigned, 8bits-wide number that i need to add/subtract together. Below the example:

```
 h_tmp <= signed(r4(calc_cnt - 2) + r4(calc_cnt - 1) + r4(calc_cnt) + 
                                        r4(calc_cnt + 1) + r4(calc_cnt + 2) - 
                                        r2(calc_cnt - 2) - r2(calc_cnt - 1) - r2(calc_cnt) -
                                        r2(calc_cnt + 1) - r2(calc_cnt + 2));
```

I know that a 13 bit wide result is ok for the numbers that I have, so i defined h_tmp as a signed (12 downto 0). Now, after synthesis I have the following warning

```
Width mismatch. <h_tmp> has a width of 13 bits but assigned expression is 8-bit wide.
```

It seems that the synthesiser inferred a 8bits-wide result of the calculation, what have I done incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the addition/subtraction (`+`/`-`) is based on the `ieee.numeric_std`
package (or `ieee.std_logic_arith` and `ieee.std_logic_unsigned`), the result
length of an addition/subtraction is that of the longest argument.

So if all your arguments in the addition/subtraction chain are 8 bits long,
then all the additions are made as 8-bit additions/subtractions, even through
you assign to a 13-bit result.

So start the addition/subtraction chain with resize of the first argument to
the length of the result, like below for `ieee.numeric_std` package:

```
h_tmp <= signed(resize(r4(calc_cnt - 2), h_tmp'length) + r4(calc_cnt - 1) ...
```

For `ieee.std_logic_arith` package use `conv_unsigned`.